# How do I create a tear effect at the bottom of a cropped image in Paint.net?

Tags: images, paint.net

How do I create a tear effect at the bottom of a cropped image in Paint.net?

Here's an example of what I'm looking for (I'm just looking to produce the tear along the bottom):

[image]

I vaguely remember Windows Live Writer being able to do this with a minimum of fuss.

Comment: I believe the above screen shot was taken with snagit itself

Comment: @Dave - yeah, I don't remember where I found it, one of the SQL blogs I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you can easily create this effect with [techsmith's](http://www.techsmith.com/) [Snagit](http://www.techsmith.com/snagit/) application

I even believe Microsoft word has a similar effect.

but I don't know of a easy way less then a plugin to create this effect

Comment: I've used snagit to great effect before for this and been very satisfied.

Comment: That's a very cool tool, I've been using WinSnap, I may have to defect. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The last time I did something like this (in Corel Photopaint), I actually scanned in a piece of torn paper and used it as the background with a little edge enhancement and shadowing.